# Inject same asset twice in webpack with different publicPath

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a `publicPath` set to `/static/dist/`, which is resulting in the below injected result. However I also want to inject this at a base path `/`. Can I inject twice using webpack ?

I am in the middle of a migration that is requiring me to keep the `index.html` to work from a sub-folder as well its on domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title id="app-title">Sample Application</title>
      <link href="/static/dist/main.eca71bee66d7a1bdc59d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
      <body style="margin: 0">
        <noscript>
          You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dist/main.eca71bee66d7a1bdc59d.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want to get an output template with 2 script tags; presumably by supporting 2 `publicPath`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/dist/main.eca71bee66d7a1bdc59d.min.js">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.eca71bee66d7a1bdc59d.min.js">
```

This is my current config.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: configUtils.webpackMode,

    devtool: configUtils.webpackDevTool,

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),

    entry: configUtils.entryFile,

    output: {
        filename: configUtils.appJsFileName,
        chunkFilename: configUtils.appJsChunkFileName,
        path: configUtils.localPublishDir,
        publicPath: '/static/dist'
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json']
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File Manager Plugin to multiple times and generate 2 index.html files if needed
`https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin`